# How to dynamically compile source files into assembly in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am aware of a class called AssemblyBuilder, and I would have thought I could use it to pass a folder containing C# source files, or pass a single C# source file to it in order to compile the source  into an assembly (.dll) which can then be referenced in a config file.

I'm aware of csc.exe which can compile C#, and I'm effectively looking for a way to replicate this dynamically.

I couldn't figure out how to use AssemblyBuilder, or whether this is the wrong class to be using, or whether I should be doing something similar to the following:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Can you point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Any reason you can't call `csc.exe` directly, passing the paths of the `.cs` files you want to compile?

Comment: Even if this is technically possible (as described in the linked article) I have the sneaking suspicion that you are trying to do something trivial in an awkward way. maybe you'll get a better solution if you describe your use case on a higher level.

Comment: The project files used in msbuild are becoming unmanageable due to the size of them, so we are writing a replacement which can harness the power of C#.To use csc.exe alone, we will have to go through a change process with the client as all code we do is sent to a central repository on the client network, where the code is built, all of which may take up to 6 months to get acceptance, so we want to avoid this as we will have to stick with msbuild for 6 months.

Comment: @Bonner So you basically want to write a replacement for MSBuild?

Comment: In essence yes, but using C# opposed to XML, and we can't use csc, so we need some way to compile C#. Our preference is to write something in C# to do this, we are tempted to take Rosalyn as suggested in another comment, but we are open to ideas at the moment.

Comment: We have looked at cmake, and a few other solutions, but we really like the idea of using C# so that we can keep the language we use consistent.

Comment: @Bonner I still don't get it. _Why_ can't you use `csc.exe`? It's part of the .NET Framework: if the Framework is installed, then the C# compiler is installed. Same for MSBuild. Whichever code compilation approach you come up with, you will still need to invoke the C# compiler at some point (unless you go down the route of Reflection Emit which seems unlikely based on what you've posted). You seem to want to replace MSBuild because of the size of the XML build files it uses, but I would have thought the XML parsing time pales into insignificance compared to your overall compile/build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into [CodeDomProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example snippet:

```
CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters
                                           {
                                               GenerateExecutable = false,
                                               GenerateInMemory = true,
                                               IncludeDebugInformation = false
                                           };

            parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
            CodeDomProvider compiler = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"); 

            return compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parms, source);
```

Warning: assemblies built dynamically in this fashion won't be handled by the garbage collector.

Comment: is there any way around the gc issue?

Comment: Not that I know of. I wonder if there's a smart way to use Rosalyn for this.